# NDVI time series and axis limits

Tags: r, ggplot2

My code is to plot NDVI versus time. here is the code below

```
ggplot(data = EdinburghNDVI, aes(x = EdinburghNDVIDate, y = NDVI)) +
  geom_point(color = "blue") +
  labs(title = "Edinburgh NDVI",
       x = "Date",
       y = "NDVI")
```

When I try to add ylim I get an error saying that there is a discrete value supplied to continuous scale.

#### Representative data

```
> head(EdinburghNDVIDate) 
[1] "2000-02-24" "2000-02-25" "2000-02-26" "2000-02-27" "2000-02-28" "2000-02-29" 

> head(EdinburghNDVI$NDVI) 
[1] 0.39 0.48 0.47 0.47 0.47 0.47 82 

Levels: -0.07 -0.08 -0.23 -0.24 -0.35 #DIV/0! 0.00 0.01 0.02 0.03 0.04 0.05 0.06 0.07 0.08 0.09 0.10 0.11 ... 0.76 –
```

Comment: Would you provide some representative data (a few rows would be enough...) :)

Comment: > head(EdinburghNDVIDate)
[1] "2000-02-24" "2000-02-25" "2000-02-26" "2000-02-27" "2000-02-28" "2000-02-29"
> head(EdinburghNDVI$NDVI)
[1] 0.39 0.48 0.47 0.47 0.47 0.47
82 Levels: -0.07 -0.08 -0.23 -0.24 -0.35 #DIV/0! 0.00 0.01 0.02 0.03 0.04 0.05 0.06 0.07 0.08 0.09 0.10 0.11 ... 0.76

Comment: I fixed the problem, I removed all the #DIV!0 values